# How to use shared_ptr on a 3'd party class with protected destructor and public destroy method

Tags: c++, boost, destructor, shared-ptr, protected

I am a client of a class A which it's destructor is defined in protected. In addition I cannot change it's interface (I deliberately wrote "3'd party class", although I meant that for any reason, you aren't allowed to change its interface.
So, How can I use boost::shared_ptr  in such case?
The destructor is virtual:

```
Class Foo {
    public:
        void Destroy () {}
    protected:
    virtual ~Foo () {}
}
```

For Foo, it provide a "Destroy" method

A Straight forward usage
The following code won't compile:

```
  boost::shared_ptr <Foo> a = boost::make_shared <Foo> ();
```

Compiler message:
...
error ..."Foo::~Foo() is inaccessible
...

Also, my workplace's compiler does not support c++11

Comment: Is the destructor virtual ?

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention...

Comment: What are you trying to do because the information you've provided does not indicate there is anything wrong with doing std::shared_ptr<A>.

Comment: using straight forward shared_ptr without any custom deleter generates compiler error. boost::shared_ptr default deleter calls ~A

Comment: Custom deleter doesn't have to call a destructor provided the Destroy function calls it.

Comment: @Eric Fortin beside the Destroy function I need to delete the pointer of Foo held by shared_ptr object. how to define such custom deleter?

Comment: @Chris Drew no it's not a duplication - see the title: "3'd party class" - you cannot change the class interface

Comment: `~InfoDialog` -> `~Foo`.

Comment: @Chris Drew please remove the possible duplication, it's certainly a different case!

Comment: @hellfire769: Done. The principle that you need a custom deleter with access is still true though, no?

Comment: @ Chris Drew indeed true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an intermediate class as a helper polymorphic base:

Sample using only c++03 **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52d36b2ce40859a7)**:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class Foo { // "abstract"
    public:
        virtual void Destroy () { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
    protected:
        virtual ~Foo () {}
};

class FooBase : public Foo {
    public:
        static void Deleter(FooBase* p) {
            if (p)
                p->Destroy();
            delete p;
        }

    // protected:
        virtual ~FooBase() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
};

class FooDerived : public FooBase
{
    ~FooDerived() { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<FooBase> p(new FooDerived, FooBase::Deleter);
}
```

Prints:

```
Destroy
~FooDerived
~FooBase
```

**Note** How the destructor could **actually** be `protected` now. That ensures that all destructions go through `FooBase::Deleter`

Comment: Maybe `FooDerived` derives `Foo` directly in OP's case.. If not, that's such a good solution!

Comment: **Fixed**. No longer using `boost::bind` now. Note that the destructor can be nice and private now, if you wish (/cc @ikh)

Comment: @sehe why is FooDerived defined? isn't FooBase enough?

Comment: @hellfire769 `FooDerived` is an example class which derives `Foo`. but the solution can be used if all classes which derive `Foo` can be modified.

Comment: I wanted to /demonstrate/ that polymorphic behaviour is respected (you **can** set the shared pointer to a derived pointer). Also, don't forget, `FooBase` has the sole purpose to server as a 'deletable' go-between.

Answer (score 0):

simple.

```
boost::shared_ptr<Foo> ptr(new Foo(), [](Foo *p){ p->Destroy(); });
```

---

**Conclusion of replies:** This is the problem of library's bad design pattern (the destructor of abstract class should be `public`..). So you can't use `shared_ptr` with this library, or you should change the destructor into `public` to use `shared_ptr` by editing library's header file, even if it is **so bad**.

Comment: Note, he's using boost::shared_ptr

Comment: Does the deleter need to call `delete` on `p` also?

Comment: in boost - will the raw pointer be deallocated (when reference count is 0)?

Comment: @ChrisDrew Well, maybe the 3rd-party library do delete object internally.

Comment: @hellfire769 No. I specify deleter, so `shared_ptr` call the deleter instead `delete p;`.

Comment: @user2675345 member function pointer isn't functor. (Is `(&A::Destroy)(p);` legal?). you should use `ptr(new Foo(), std::mem_fn(&A::Destroy))`.

Comment: Is std::mem_fn a c++11 feature? I an not allowed to use c++11

Comment: @ikh Thanks. Yeah I didn't read the signature of the deleter properly.

Comment: @ChrisDrew no, Destroy does not call ~Foo

Comment: @hellfire769 then, you can use `std::mem_fun` which is deprecated after C++11. for example: `std::mem_fun(&A::Destroy)`

Comment: @hellfire769 What?? If so, `Foo::~Foo` cannot be called except its friends, So you cannot use `Foo`.

Comment: I'm still confused. When defining a custom deleter, when reference count reach 0, and the custom deleter is called, will the raw pointer of Foo (Foo*) be deleted?
If I define a Null Deleter, Foo* isn't deleted

Comment: @ikh - why? and what about inheriting Foo which will have access to ~Foo? class FooDerived: public Foo?

Comment: @hellfire769 I think the creator of this library intended to "`Foo` is abstract class, and it should be used by polymorphism.", but that library code is so bad... only the constructor of `Foo` must be `protected`, and destructor must be `public` (and pure-virtual, optionally). Anyway, since you cannot modify library code, you cannot use `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @hellfire769 The point is, in the deleter you can **and should** do everything that you normally should. You never showed us that relevant code, so we can't show you the equivalent thing?

Comment: @hellfire769 But you might change its destructor into public, by modify only header file. It is against standard, but it won't matter in most cases.

Comment: @hellfire769 http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#destructor "**If *this is empty**, or shares ownership with another shared_ptr instance (use_count() > 1), there are no side effects.". So deleter is never called with null pointer.

Comment: sorry, @ikh that's ***exceptionally*** bad advice (changing the header). It violates the ODR. It's not against the standard, it's just plain unreliable. The class layout might even change. So don't. Also, `delete nullptr;` is fine. No problem

Comment: @sehe I know to modify library header is bad, but `shared_ptr` is too nice feature to give up..

Comment: @ikh You're completely missing the point. You don't **need** to change this. If the destructor is private, you **couldn't call `delete` on it anyway**, with or without smart pointers. It's probably not intended to be manually deleted.

Comment: @sehe By OP's explanation, the creator of library might intend to "Foo is abstract class". (destructor is `protected`, not `private`.) I think it is mistake of the creator of library (as I say my reply), So I suggest that.

Comment: @sehe Just updated - c++11 isn't available to me, thus can;t use nullptr

Comment: @ikh - *this isn't empty after Destroy, it's merely destroyed

Comment: The creator of Foo may have written a bad API, but I can't do anything about it

Comment: @hellfire769 you can, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22658739/85371). Sorry ikr for not getting it at first

Comment: @sehe I'm saying that is against standard: the class layout can change, but library code (maybe object file) isn't reflected.

Comment: I agree after reading the question better that `Foo` has a design problem. You already had my +1 from the first minute, so can't +1 more :)

Comment: @hellfire769 `nullptr` is not magic. It's just a value, with a type that makes it clearer which implicit conversions exist. The point was that deleting a null pointer (which ever way you choose to spell it, NULL, 0, 0x0, T*() ...) is perfectly fine.

Comment: @sehe I know what nullptr is. As marked in the description, my compiler doesn't support it.